# Spring boot app running in docker can't access external servers under test profile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I wrote a spring boot app that I am dockerizing.  My app communicates with a mongodb (running locally on my box) and with a rabbitMq server (running in a docker container locally on my box).  Running under my *dev* profile (having replaced *localhost* or *127.0.0.1* with *host.docker.internal) everything works.

Here is my Dockerfile

```js
# Filename: Dockerfile
# It is assumed that you are in the root directory for this project

FROM  openjdk:8    
ADD /target/monitor-msg-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  monitor-msg-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 11371

## Profile: dev
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Dlog_home=/tmp","monitor-msg-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I create an image, then run that image using the following command:

```js
docker run  --network=host  -p 11371:11371  -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" --name monitor-msg-consumer   monitor-msg-consumer-img:latest
```

And as stated the app runs and I can interact with it under the *dev* profile.

Now, if I delete that container and run it with my *test* profile using the command:

```js
docker run  --network=host  -p 11371:11371  -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test" --name monitor-msg-consumer   monitor-msg-consumer-img:latest
```

the app can't find an **external rabbitMq** server running in our test environment.

What am I missing?

I am new to docker.  So, go easy on me!

### Here are the logs from the docker container:

```js
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)
2019-09-30T12:46:43.344207600Z 
12:46:44,049 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@62fdb4a6 - URL [jar:file:/monitor-msg-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml] is not of type file
12:46:44,053 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [jar:file:/monitor-msg-consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml] 
12:46:44,053 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds
12:46:44,054 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
12:46:44,054 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
12:46:44,055 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
12:46:44,056 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
12:46:44,057 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
12:46:44,059 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@500179317 - No compression will be used
12:46:44,061 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@500179317 - Will use the pattern /tmp/archived/monitor_msg_consumer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
12:46:44,062 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@31206beb - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/tmp/archived/monitor_msg_consumer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'.
12:46:44,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@31206beb - Roll-over at midnight.
12:46:44,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@31206beb - Setting initial period to Mon Sep 30 12:46:42 UTC 2019
12:46:44,068 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@31206beb - SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP is deprecated. Use SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy instead
12:46:44,068 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@31206beb - For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy
12:46:44,068 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: /tmp/monitor_msg_consumer.log
12:46:44,068 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [/tmp/monitor_msg_consumer.log]
12:46:44,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [gov.utah.dts.monitor] to DEBUG
12:46:44,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3e77a1ed - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[gov.utah.dts.monitor] onto the JUL framework
12:46:44,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
12:46:44,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
12:46:44,069 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
12:46:44,070 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
12:46:44,070 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@3ffcd140 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2019-09-30 12:46:44 | ERROR | [main] o.s.c.l.LoggingRebinder:83 - Cannot set level: WARN   #(Options: DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN) for 'org.springframework'
12:46:44,074 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@3e77a1ed - Propagating WARN level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
2019-09-30 12:46:44 | ERROR | [main] o.s.c.l.LoggingRebinder:83 - Cannot set level: DEBUG  #(Options: DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN) for 'gov.utah.dts.monitor'
2019-09-30 12:46:44 | ERROR | [main] o.s.c.l.LoggingRebinder:83 - Cannot set level: DEBUG          #(Options: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN) for 'gov.utah.dts'
2019-09-30 12:46:44 | INFO  | [main] g.u.d.m.MainApp:651 - The following profiles are active: test
2019-09-30 12:46:54 | INFO  | [main] g.u.d.m.MainApp:59 - Started MainApp in 13.437 seconds (JVM running for 14.251)
12:47:14,053 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling 
12:47:44,053 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling 
12:48:14,053 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling 
12:48:44,054 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling 
12:49:14,053 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling 
12:49:44,052 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeTask(born:1569847604053) - Empty watch file list. Disabling
```

This code would make one think that things are running smoothly, but what I do not see on the rabbitMq server, itself, is a consumer that should be this application.  That is why I believe it is not working.

When I run this application non-dockerized, then I see the consumer for the specified queue.

Here are application-test.properties:

```js
#Port Range 11370 - 11379
server:
  port: 11371

spring:
  ## Rabbit
  rabbitmq:
    host: 172.23.2.12
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
  ## MongoDB
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 172.23.1.242
      port: 20000
      database: ********** 
      username: **********
      password: **********
      # Only required if you're hitting a local database w/o username and pswd
      uri: mongodb://**********:**********@***.***.***.242:20000/**********

rabbitmq:
  queue: erepMonitorQueue
  durable: true  
  exchange: erepMonitorExchg
  route: erepMonitorRoute
  
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    # Only print warning messages and above from external libraries
    gov.utah.dts: DEBUG          #(Options: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN)
    gov.utah.dts.monitor: DEBUG  #(Options: DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN)
    org.springframework: INFO    #(Options: DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, WARN)
```

Comment: can you ping to that external rabbitMq server from the machine that you are running docker container?  Can you show the docker logs.

Comment: @Keaz  yes.

Pinging 172.23.2.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.23.2.12: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.23.2.12: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.23.2.12: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.23.2.12: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 172.23.2.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 2ms

Comment: can you show the test profile. Are you using rabbitMq server ip or hostname.

Comment: @Keaz  I have added the application-test.properties.  I use the IP of the server running the remote rabbitMq.  

I should also note that in my dev environment rabbitMq is running in another docker container.  Since docker containers tend to share a network by default that may be the difference.  I just do not know.

Comment: Are you using linux machine, can you add a hostname for you test rabbitmq server like '172.23.1.242 rabbitmq'. Then in the application-test.properties change the rabbitmq ip to new hostname.

Comment: @Keaz  I am on a windows box.  The rabbitMq server is a linux box.  I can try to set up a host name for the IP.  What is your reasoning for doing this?  I will have to research how to do this on my box.  I will get back to you when it is done.

Comment: Normally docker network range starts with 172 and you rabbitmq host ip in the 172 range. So maybe your rabbitmq host is not reachable from the docker network. You can add a hot entry to this file C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.

Comment: @Keaz  You're correct!   I googled and found the same answer.  I have made that change.  I ran the app non-docker and I saw the consumer appear.  But, I still have the same problem once I fire it up in a docker container.  I do not see the consumer on the rabbitMq queue.

Comment: can you change the docker default bridge network. You can do it from editing 
/etc/docker/daemon.json(in linux).
{
  "bip": "173.26.0.1/16"
}

Comment: @Keaz  I tried a *docker network create* option:  **docker network create --driver=bridge --ip-range=173.26.0.1/16 --subnet=173.26.0.0/16 monitor-test**  Is this command correct to get what you are asking me?  I then brought up the application using the *--network* option ( --network=monitor-test).  Still no change.  I do not see a consumer on the specified queue.